# Variables not propagating to PHP include file

Tags: php, include

I have a file called `index.php` and in this file there is a variable called `$mainDir`, I would like this variable to be used in the file that is included,

**Example:**

```
<?php // index.php
    $mainDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    if ($isTest){ // presume this is true
        include $mainDir . 'test.php';
    }
?>
// Different File:
<?php // test.php
    echo $mainDir;
?>
```

I have looked at the other solutions and I have placed the variable I want before the include statement and the include statement is being called properly, it just gives me a warning that the variable that I want to use in the included file is not set.

Comment: Your example looks fine. However, are you doing the include in a function in your actual version? If you have it in a function, then the global won't be available without using global.

Answer (score 1):

`dirname(__FILE__);` doesn't include a "/" at the end I believe. To fix this, simply use this as your include:

```
 include $mainDir.'/test.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this :

```
<?php // index.php
    $mainDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    if ($isTest){ // presume this is true
        include $mainDir . 'test.php';
    }
    $_GET["mainDir"] = $mainDir;
?>
// Different File:
<?php // test.php
    echo $_GET["mainDir"];
?>
```

it's horrible but it should works.

Comment: Why would that work? It's not really any different than the original, only adds a get variable which you don't have any reason to. This answer is not correct.